# Is there paint without texture?

Tags: painting, paint, canvas

Recently, I have been trying to paint over a painting I've painted before but don't like. Unfortunately, every time I paint over it, it leaves a weird texture or it sort of soaks into the canvas and leaves weird marks and you can still see the painting underneath it. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening or is there a certain pant I should use?

Comment: Can you give more details? What's the paint you're working with, what type of paint are you attempting to cover, what type of canvas are you working on, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try sandpaper or even an environmentally friendly (low fume) paint stripper. Other solvents might also be a worth a try, for example mineral turps for oil. Another option is to use a heat gun to soften it and then scrape it off with a flat bladed scraper used for plastering. I did this today successfully, just don’t touch the blade as it gets extremely hot after being near the heat gun.

Unless you can add a very thick layer higher than the depth of the original's texture, I think you'll have the same problem.

If the canvas is mounted on board, it is easier to scrape off. If it's a stretched canvass, you might need to be more careful in the scraping part -- you don't want to catch the (sharp-edged) scraper in the canvass and make a tear.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply a thick layer of the canvas preparation, Gesso, over the existing paint.  That will handle the absorbency issues and somewhat reduce the texture issue.

Comment: Depending on the paint used this could be a bad idea.

Comment: @Joachim, for all of our sakes, could you be more specific about why it is a bad idea and which paints produce specific negative results.  Leaving us to experimenting to find what you already know is exactly opposite of what this forum is about.

Comment: It was meant as a reference to my comment on the OP. For example, you shouldn't cover up oil paints with gesso, since they have very different curing times. That's why I said it *could* be a bad idea - not that it was :)